# List components must be used inside a <ListContext.Provider> - react-admin 3.8.5

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-admin

I'm using react-admin 3.8.5 and I get this console message every time I use the `List` component.
This console message shouts dozen of times and happens only when I'm inside development mode:

[image]

From what I've read, I should wrap my List component inside a `ListContextProvider` but I didn't managed to do so properly without harming my `List`.

Here's my `List` component:

```
import React from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import TimeZonesFilter from "./filter";
import EmptyPage from "../../../components/Resource/EmptyPage";
import ShowButton from "../../../components/Buttons/ShowButton.tsx";
import { Paginator } from "../../../components/Resource/Paginator";
import ListActions from "../../../components/Resource/ListActions";
import {
    List,
    Datagrid,
    TextField,
    ChipField,
    EditButton,
    FunctionField,
} from "react-admin";

export const TimeZonesList = (props) => (
    <List
        title="Time Zones"
        filters={<TimeZonesFilter />}
        pagination={<Paginator />}
        perPage={15}
        {...props}
        empty={<EmptyPage />}
        actions={<ListActions listExporterType="TimeZones" />}
    >
        <Datagrid id="time_zones-table">
            <TextField source="id" label="ID" />
            <ChipField source="iso" label="ISO" />
            <TextField source="name" />
            <FunctionField
                label="Created At"
                source="created_at"
                render={(record) =>
                    record.created_at && (
                        <Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{moment(record.created_at)}</Moment>
                    )
                }
            />

            <FunctionField
                label="Updated At"
                source="updated_at"
                render={(record) =>
                    record.updated_at && (
                        <Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY">{moment(record.updated_at)}</Moment>
                    )
                }
            />
            <EditButton />
            <ShowButton />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

Would love to have your help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The warnings will be shown in development mode thats may be the reason you doesn't see the warnings in your production one. I think as its clear if the component boundary is outside the context it will show this warning

Comment: Weird, as you're using react-admin's `<List>`, you shouldn't see this warning. Do you, by any chance, have mismatched versions of ra-core, ra-ui-material-ui, and react-admin in your package.json?